# Node.js remote mp3 file duration and bitrate

Tags: node.js

I have webisite with a lot of mp3 link , i wants show each mp3 link duration and bitrate. after some research i found this libraries : [Taglib](https://github.com/nikhilm/node-taglib) , [MusicMetadata](https://github.com/leetreveil/musicmetadata) , [id3js](https://github.com/43081j/id3)

but its seems to be these libraries only work with local files.
i just want know there is any way to do this without downloading files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Node can't do that itself (with `fs` or similar). At some point, it will require some OS-dependant binary tools to get information like duration or bitrate.

I would go with [mp3info](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mp3info) npm package which embed the mp3info tool for linux.

Also, one should avoid to calculate the duration with the size and the bitrate as the bitrate can be constant or variable ie non predictable.